# An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf

Tags: sharepoint-api

I have a problem with requesting sharepoint at "https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf" using Postman or Java/Spring RestTemplate in order to get my security token.

[Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiScv.jpg)

[Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5skq.jpg)

[Response OK (200) but while expecting a SOAP envelope containing my security token, I receive an envelope containing the error status 0x80045b00 with no documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gwAl.jpg)

At your disposal for any further information.

Thank you for your help.

PS : also waiting for a reply in [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/an-error-occurred-while-receiving-the-http/eac1d15e-bed9-4e16-85c3-447aa62427a4)